# How do I do JavaScript Array Animation

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game but don't know how to do Array Animation with the png Array and game Surface that I made below. I'm trying to make it so that when the Right arrow key is pressed, the character animates as if it is walking to the right and when the Left arrow key is pressed it animates as if it is walking to the left (kind of like Mario). I put everything on a surface instead of the canvas. Everything is explained in the code below. I couldn't find help on this anywhere. I hope what I got below makes sense. I'm basically a beginner with JavaScript. I'll be back if more is needed:

```
   <!doctype html5> 

     <html>

    <head></head>
    <script src="graphics.js"></script>
    <script src="object.js"></script>


    <body onkeydown ="keyDown(event)" onkeyup ="keyUp(event)" ></body>

    <script>

    //"Surface" is where I want to display my animation. It's like the HTML 
     // canvas but it's not that. It's just the surface to where everything in the 
     //game and the game itself will be displayed.

    var Surface = new Graphics(600, 400, "skyblue");



    //here's the array that I want to use for animation

var player = new Array("StandsRight.png", "WalksRight.png", "StandsLeft.png","WalksLeft.png" );




 //Here is the X coordinate, Y coordinate, the beginning png for the animation, 
 //and the object's name "player." I also turned the array into an object (but
 //I don't know if I was supposed to do that or not).

 var player = new Object(50, 100, 40, 115, "StandsRight.png","player");



//When doing animation I know that it requires a "loop", but I don't
// know how to connect it so that it works with the arrays so that
//it could animate.

    var loop = 0;



//this actually puts "player" on screen. It makes player visible and
//it is where I would like the animation to occur.

 Surface.drawObject(player);


//this would be the key that makes "player" animation in the righward direction
function keyDown(e) {

if (e.keyCode == 39); 

 }


//this would be the key that makes "player" animation in the leftward direction
function keyUp(e){


if (e.keyCode == 39); 


 }



 //this is the Mainloop where the game will function
 MainLoop();


 //the mainloop functionized
 function MainLoop(){


 //this is how fast or slow I could want the entire game to go
 setTimeout(MainLoop, 10);


   }


 </script>

  </html>
```

---

From here, are the "graphic.js" and the "object.js" files below. In this section is the graphics.js file. This graphics.js part below is linked to the: script src="graphics.js">  html script section that I wrote above. Basically, below is a seperate file that I used for Graphics, and to run the code above, make this graphics.js code that I post below here, a separate filed called: graphics.js

```
function Graphics(w,h,c) {

   document.body.innerHTML += "<table style='position:absolute;font-   
   size:0;top:0;left:0;border-spacing:0;border-
    width:0;width:"+w+";height:"+h+";background-color:"+c+";' border=1><tr><td>

    </table>\n";


  this.drawRectangle = function(x,y,w,h,c,n) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div style='position:absolute;font-size:0;left:" + x + 
  ";top:" + y + ";width:" + w + ";height:" + h + ";background-color:" + c + ";' id='" 
   + n + "'></div>\n"; 
     }

   this.drawTexture = function(x,y,w,h,t,n) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<img style='position:absolute;font-size:0;left:" + x + 
  ";top:" + y + ";width:" + w + ";height:" + h + ";' id='" + n + "' src='" + t + "'>
   </img>\n"; 
    }


   this.drawObject = function(o) {

    document.body.innerHTML += "<img style='position:absolute;font-size:0;left:" + 
    o.X + ";top:" + o.Y + ";width:" + o.Width + ";height:" + o.Height + ";' id='" + 
    o.Name + "' src='" + o.Sprite + "'></img>\n"; 
     }

    this.moveGraphic = function(x,y,n) {

    document.getElementById(n).style.left = x;
     document.getElementById(n).style.top = y;
      }


     this.removeGraphic = function(n){
     document.getElementById(n).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(n));
      }


     }
```

Finally, is the object.js file linked to the script src="object.js">" in the html game file above the graphics.js part I just wrote. Basically, this is a separate file too, so thus, in order to run or test the html game code in the very first section I wrote, a person has to also make this code below a separate file called: object.js

I hope this helps:

```
  function Object(x,y,w,h,t,n) {
  this.X = x;
  this.Y = y;
  this.Velocity_X = 0;
  this.Velocity_Y = 0;
  this.Previous_X = 0;
  this.Previous_Y = 0;
  this.Width = w;
  this.Height = h;
  this.Sprite = t;
  this.Name = n;
  this.Exists = true;
                              }
```

In all, this game is made based on a tutorial on youtube at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2kUzgFM4lY&feature=relmfu

I'm just trying to learn how to add animations with it now. 
I hope the above helps. If not, let me know. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you put your script tags in the `<head>`. That makes sure that it's loaded before the buttons, links, and the like, not that you might need it, but it's standard to do so. Create arrays with `[` and `]`.

Comment: Wow, I'm editing what you've provided, and your code makes zero sense, lol. I don't know what's in `object.js`, either, but it sure as hell isn't healthy.

Comment: Hey, who made those libraries?

Comment: Someone from youtube at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2kUzgFM4lY&feature=relmfu    those libraries can be gotten from the description part inside the video link under the word "classes"

Comment: OK, that video is awful. Use <canvas>, for Christ's sake, unless you really need DOM.

Comment: Ok, I'm opened to learning how to do that with the Canvas as well. I learned with that video because it seemed the closest thing to game programming with BlitzBasic (I got so used to BlitzBasic) thus, that's the reason I tried to do things like that video), but I'm willing to learn alternative ways too. Thanks

Comment: This is the most complete and yet easy tutorial I found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/. Also, for general gamedev, you can use our wiki: http://vidyadev.com/wiki/Main_Page. It's awful, but we're adding things, and we're a community as well, so that might come in handy.

Comment: I saw the "developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial" before, and it shows how to move an object on screen and yet they call that animation (and there are many tutorials on how to move things. But I was trying to learn how to do  png animation to where it seems like there is a character doing the motion of walking, etc. (like Mario). Such has been hard to find for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Don't do that "`Object`" thing! "`Object`" is the base constructor function for every object in Javascript! And you're overwriting it!

```
x = new Object(); //Is the same as
y = {}; //this.
```

You're going to mess things up if you overwrite `Object`. Find a new name, like simply "`Player`". Then, do `player = new Player(arguments)`. I'm not saying that `Object` gets executed each time you make an object, nor that the function actually does something important, but it's a generally bad idea to do things like these.

---

As I've said in the comment, your code makes little sense. What does the `object.js`  file do? Anyway, here's your code, but with a bit of `sense` put into. I say "bit", because I still don't know how you are handling images or what `new Object()` does (or even better, what you **think** it does).

```
    <script>
        //For rendering (drawing), use window.requestAnimationFrame(nameOfRenderFunction). It's simple to setTimeout, only you don't need to worry about FPS, as the browser will do various optimizations for you.

        //You can ignore this. It just fixes the fact that different browser engines have different names for this function.
        window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
          return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
                  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
                  window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
                  window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
                  function( callback ){
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                  };
        })();

        //This happens when ANY key on the keyboard is pressed.
        function keyDown(e) 
        {
            //If the key is the right arrow
            if (e.keyCode == 39); 
            {
                player.image = playerImages[1]; //This doesn't do any animation, though.
            }
        }

        function mainLoop() //Function names start with a lowercase letter.
        {
            timePassed = new Date().getTime() - timePassed; //new Date().getTime() returns the current time in milliseconds.

            //Do logic. (Check if key is pressed, then move the player accordingly by playerSpeed*timePassed, for example).
        }

        function render()
        {
            if (rendering)
            {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
            }

            Surface.drawObject(player);
        }

        //This gets called once the page loads. It's a useful technique.
        var init = function()
        {
            //If you declare variables without the var prefix, they become global (which means that you can use them in any function).
            Surface = new Graphics(600, 400, "skyblue");

            playerImages = ["StandsRight.png", "WalksRight.png", "StandsLeft.png","WalksLeft.png"]; //These are only the sources, you'll want to load the images and put them here.
            player = new Object(50, 100, 40, 115, "StandsRight.png","player"); //I'm not sure what is this supposed to do... Object is a built-in Javascript "class", this doesn't do anything. But I guess that's changed in you "object.js" file, but you should definetivly avoid this. 

            //It's good to separate logic from rendering.
            var LPS = 30; //Logic per second.

            setInterval(mainLoop, 1000/LPS);

            rendering = true; //Set to false when you want to stop rendering.
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body onload="init();" onkeydown ="keyDown(event);" onkeyup ="keyUp(event);">
</body>
```

If you want, I can write this through, completely. For that, I will use my [Loader.js](https://github.com/Yannbane/loader.js) utility, which I recommend you use as well. I assure you that this code will not work, because you're working with *strings*, not *image objects*.

Comment: Ok, I'll redo the code above and include the "graphics.js" and "object.js." The reason I didn't include it is because I thought it would be a lot to sift through. I'll be back momentarily

Comment: Can you upload them somewhere else? If it's too lengthy, don't put entire frameworks here.

Comment: I went back and edited my the code above. If it's too lenghthy, I'll be glad to repost it in such a way that it's not lengthy. But basically, I just added the two files: the graphics.js     and the     object.js that are to be made separate from the first html file I wrote. Thanks

Comment: Edited! As I said, a proper answer will come "tomorrow".

Comment: Bane, I'm sorry that it took me a while to come back. I tried to run the code you created above, but the browser said that there was something wrong with the "var init" part and it didn't run.

Comment: @Henry, sorry, I forgot to add the `... = function()` part. Also, this is just the concept, you don't have to copy, rather just study it. If there are any more errors, please report. And tell me what exactly the browsers says, "something wrong" doesn't really help.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to add that and work with it more and diagnose the problem if there are any. Again, sorry for the late response. I was out of town for a couple of weeks.

Comment: No problem, man. Just report any bugs here, there might be more.

Comment: Bane, thanks for the help. I was able to get it to work.

Comment: Ok, I will. You were a huge help